# react js class poll convert into react hooks poll

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express, mern

this my code for react component "class" base poll but I want to convert this form into  react hooks so need help...!I don't understand How can I do this?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";

// Declaring poll question and answers
const pollQuestion = "Youtube is the best place to learn ?";
const pollAnswers = [
  { option: "Yes", votes: 7 },
  { option: "No", votes: 2 },
  { option: "don't know", votes: 1 },
];

class Fakepolls extends Component {
  // Setting answers to state to reload the component with each vote
  state = {
    pollAnswers: [...pollAnswers],
  };

  // Handling user vote
  // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes
  handleVote = (voteAnswer) => {
    const { pollAnswers } = this.state;
    const newPollAnswers = pollAnswers.map((answer) => {
      if (answer.option === voteAnswer) answer.votes++;
      return answer;
    });
    this.setState({
      pollAnswers: newPollAnswers,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { pollAnswers } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Poll
          question={pollQuestion}
          answers={pollAnswers}
          onVote={this.handleVote}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Fakepolls;
```

Comment: What is there to convert into a React hook? Do you mean to convert a class-based component to a functional component? What have you tried that isn't working?

Comment: yes you are right ..! class-based component to functional component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will, for this answer, assume you are rather asking about how to convert a class-based component to a functional component since there isn't anything really to convert to a custom react hook.

Steps to convert:

1. Convert state to use the `useState` React hook.
2. Replace references of `this.state.pollAnswers` to `pollAnswers`.
3. Replace references to `this.setState` to `setPollAnswers`.
4. Use proper functional state update to ***not*** mutate existing state.
5. Replace reference of `this.handleVote` to `handleVote` and declare `const`.

Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";

// Declaring poll question and answers
const pollQuestion = "Youtube is the best place to learn ?";
const answers = [ // <-- renamed to avoid collision with state variable
  { option: "Yes", votes: 7 },
  { option: "No", votes: 2 },
  { option: "don't know", votes: 1 }
];

const Fakepolls = () => {
  // Setting answers to state to reload the component with each vote
  const [pollAnswers, setPollAnswers] = useState([...answers]);

  // Handling user vote
  // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes
  const handleVote = (voteAnswer) => {
    setPollAnswers((pollAnswers) =>
      pollAnswers.map((answer) =>
        answer.option === voteAnswer
          ? {
              ...answer,
              votes: answer.votes + 1
            }
          : answer
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Poll
        question={pollQuestion}
        answers={pollAnswers}
        onVote={handleVote}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Fakepolls;
```

[image: Edit react-js-class-poll-convert-into-react-hooks-poll]

Comment: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'pollAnswers' before initialization                                               const Fakepolls = () => {
  13 |   // Setting answers to state to reload the component with each vote
> 14 |   const [pollAnswers, setPollAnswers] = useState([...pollAnswers]);
  15 | 
  16 |   // Handling user vote
  17 |   // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes

Comment: @Asitsingh Ah, yeah, I hit that as well... in the sandbox I just renamed `const pollAnswers` to `const answers` to avoid the name collision with the state variable `pollAnswers`. Sorry for not explicitly calling that out in the sandbox.