# How to create a poll using an API with a React functional component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, express

This is my React code and I want to connect with my [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) API, but I don't understand how to do that...!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";
// import "./styles.css";

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896319/react-js-class-poll-convert-into-react-hooks-poll
 */

// Declaring poll question and answers
const pollQuestion = "Youtube is the best place to learn ?";
const answers = [
  { option: "Yes", votes: 7 },
  { option: "No", votes: 2 },
  { option: "don't know", votes: 1 },
];

const Fakepolls = () => {
  // Setting answers to state to reload the component with each vote
  const [pollAnswers, setPollAnswers] = useState([...answers]);

  // Handling user vote
  // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes
  const handleVote = (voteAnswer) => {
    setPollAnswers((pollAnswers) =>
      pollAnswers.map((answer) =>
        answer.option === voteAnswer
          ? {
              ...answer,
              votes: answer.votes + 1,
            }
          : answer
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Poll
        noStorage
        question={pollQuestion}
        answers={pollAnswers}
        onVote={handleVote}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Fakepolls />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It work's fine with

```
// Declaring poll question and answers
    const pollQuestion = "Youtube is the best place to learn ?";
    const answers = [
      { option: "Yes", votes: 7 },
      { option: "No", votes: 2 },
      { option: "don't know", votes: 1 },
    ];
```

but I want to connect this poll with my API instead of *declaring* it! This is my API. To get data -> (router.get("/poll/:pollId", getPoll); //)

```
exports.getPoll = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { pollId } = req.params;
    const polls = await Poll.findById(pollId);
    if (!polls) throw new Error("no polls found");
    res.status(200).json(polls);
  } catch (error) {
    error.status = 400;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

This is a [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) image -

[image]

And this is the API for the POST data. And my Node.js code:

```
     exports.votes = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    /**
     * 1. get the poll from db
     * 2. check if the user already exists in any option
     * 3. if user has already selected any option do nothing
     * 4. if user has selected any other option remove from that option
     * 5. if user does not exist in any option, insert his user id to selected option
     */
    const { pollId } = req.params;
    let { userId, answer } = req.body;
    // get selected poll from db
    const poll = await Poll.findById(pollId);
    if (answer && poll) {
      answer = answer.toLowerCase();
      ///Finf the Poll

      let existingVote = null;
      Object.keys(poll.options).forEach((option) => {
        // loop on all options, check if the user already exists in any option
        if (poll.options[option].includes(userId)) {
          existingVote = option;
        }
      });
      if (existingVote == null) {
        // if there is no existing vote save it to db
        try {
          const push = {};
          push[`options.${answer}`] = userId;
          const update = await Poll.findByIdAndUpdate(
            pollId,
            { $push: push },
            { upsert: true }
          );
          res.status(201).json(update);
        } catch (err) {
          error.status = 400;
          next(error);
        }
      } else if (existingVote && existingVote.length > 0) {
        // check if answer is same as previous, if yes send not modified
        if (existingVote.toLowerCase() === answer.toLowerCase()) {
          res.status(304).send("Response already saved");
        } else {
          // delete the previous response and save it in new
          if (
            Array.isArray(poll.options[existingVote]) &&
            poll.options[existingVote].length > 0
          ) {
            // TODO: filtering this is not returning array but 1
            poll.options[existingVote] = poll.options[existingVote].filter(
              (vote) => vote != userId
            );
            poll.options[answer] = poll.options[answer].push(userId);
            const update = await Poll.findByIdAndUpdate(pollId, {
              $set: { options: poll.options },
            });
            res.status(201).json(update);
          }
        }
      } else {
        error = {
          status: 500,
          message: "Something went wrong",
        };
        next(error);
      }
    } else {
      error = {
        status: 404,
        message: "Poll not found",
      };
      next(error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    error.status = 400;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

This is a Postman image using POST to store the data:

[image]

How can I connect the API with the React poll?

Answer (score 0):

What you'd do is make a `fetch()` to your `/api/polls` endpoint inside your `Fakepolls` component, the URL being exactly as you show in your Postman screenshot. More info on `fetch` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) at the MDN docs.

With the response you get from the endpoint, populate the `answers` array you component uses. From what I see, it would require a bit of transformation as your `answer` object is not quite the same as what `Poll` needs.

Next, upon user action, as well as updating the votes in the UI, you need to make another `fetch` to your `vote` endpoint.

Here's your component again with these adjustments. Keep in mind it's untested and the URLs are obviously not real:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";
// import "./styles.css";

/**
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896319/react-js-class-poll-convert-into-react-hooks-poll
 */

const Fakepolls = () => {
  // Setting answers to state to reload the component with each vote
  const [pollQuestion, setPollQuestion] = useState('');
  const [pollAnswers, setPollAnswers] = useState([]);

  // Query the actual poll info from the server
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://your-server/api/polls/you-poll-id')
    .then((response) => response.json()) //parse response as json
    .then((pollObject) => {
      let answerCountDictionary = Object.keys(pollObject.options)
        .map(oKey => {
          return { 
            option: oKey,
            anwers: pollObject.options[oKey].length
          }
        }); //iterate over the 'options' properties' keys to get the names and the current votes
      setPollAnswers(answerCountDictionary);
      setPollQuestion(pollObject.question)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  },[]) //adding empty array of dependencies to prevent multiple calls on state change

  // Handling user vote
  // Increments the votes count of answer when the user votes
  const handleVote = (voteAnswer) => {
    setPollAnswers((pollAnswers) =>
      pollAnswers.map((answer) =>
        answer.option === voteAnswer
          ? {
              ...answer,
              votes: answer.votes + 1,
            }
          : answer
      )
    );
    //also submit the backend
    fetch('http://your-server/api/vote/poll-id', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: {
        "userId": "the-logged-in-user",
        "answer": voteAnswer
      },
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Poll
        noStorage
        question={pollQuestion}
        answers={pollAnswers}
        onVote={handleVote}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Fakepolls />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -4):

To connect your React poll with your Node.js API, you need to perform the following steps: 1. Make an HTTP request from your React component to your Node.js API to fetch the poll data. You can use the fetch or axios library to make the request. Update your Fakepolls component to fetch the poll data from the API:

jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Poll from "react-polls";

const Fakepolls = () => {
  const [pollAnswers, setPollAnswers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPollData();
  }, []);

  const fetchPollData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/poll/:pollId"); // Replace with the actual API endpoint URL
      if (response.ok) {
        const poll = await response.json();
        const pollAnswers = poll.options.map((option) => ({
          option: option.name,
          votes: option.votes.length,
        }));
        setPollAnswers(pollAnswers);
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to fetch poll data");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while fetching poll data:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleVote = (voteAnswer) => {
    // Send the vote data to your API
    // Make an HTTP request to your API's vote endpoint, passing the selected answer and any other required data
    // Update the poll answers state after a successful response from the API
    // You can follow a similar approach as the fetchPollData function

    // Placeholder code to update the poll answers state
    setPollAnswers((prevPollAnswers) =>
      prevPollAnswers.map((answer) =>
        answer.option === voteAnswer
          ? {
              ...answer,
              votes: answer.votes + 1,
            }
          : answer
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Poll
        noStorage
        question={pollQuestion}
        answers={pollAnswers}
        onVote={handleVote}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

2. In your Node.js API, update the /poll/:pollId route to fetch the poll data from your database and return it as a response. Modify the API code as follows:

javascript

```
exports.getPoll = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { pollId } = req.params;
    const poll = await Poll.findById(pollId);
    if (!poll) throw new Error("No poll found");
    
    // Modify the poll object to match the structure expected by the React component
    const pollData = {
      question: poll.question,
      answers: poll.options.map((option) => ({
        option: option.name,
        votes: option.votes.length,
      })),
    };

    res.status(200).json(pollData);
  } catch (error) {
    error.status = 400;
    next(error);
  }
};
```

Ensure that you replace /api/poll/:pollId in the fetch call of your React component with the actual URL for your Node.js API endpoint.

Comment: Was this generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen just curious what gave u the impression it was chatGPT? I use chatGPT sometimes for springboard ideas, but curious if you see any red flags?